# Latest MonetDB in Docker container

Tags: docker, monetdb

I'm facing a new personal BI project, and my idea is based on Pentaho. I'm very interested in MonetDB as database, and I'd like to use it as a Docker container.

I came across the official MonetDB Docker Hub repository (https://hub.docker.com/r/monetdb/monetdb-r-docker), but it's based on version 11.31.7, which is more than 2 years old.

How can I get a Docker container updated to the latest MonetDB version (Oct2020)? I'd be very useful taking advantage of new features and improved speed.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The official MonetDB docker images are here: https://hub.docker.com/r/monetdb/monetdb (this is since MonetDB Oct2020-SP2 release).

The documentation is still ongoing work, until then, you can probably consult the information in the old MonetDB docker.